# GROUP BY & COUNT with multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, many-to-many

I have a simple configuration : 
2 tables linked in a many-to-many relation, so it gave me 3 tables.

Table author:

```
idAuthor INT
name VARCHAR
```

Table publication:

```
idPublication INT,
title VARCHAR,
date YEAR,
type VARCHAR,
conference VARCHAR,
journal VARCHAR
```

Table author_has_publication:

```
Author_idAuthor,
Publication_idPublication
```

I am trying to get all the authors name that have published at least 2 papers in conference SIGMOD and conference PVLDB. 
Right now I achieved this but I still have a double result. My query :

```
SELECT author.name, publication.journal, COUNT(*)
FROM author
INNER JOIN author_has_publication
    ON author.idAuthor = author_has_publication.Author_idAuthor
INNER JOIN publication
    ON author_has_publication.Publication_idPublication = publication.idPublication
GROUP BY publication.journal, author.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
   AND (publication.journal = 'PVLDB' OR  publication.journal = 'SIGMOD');
```

returns

```
+-------+---------+----------+
| name  | journal | COUNT(*) |
+-------+---------+----------+
| Renee | PVLDB   |        2 |
| Renee | SIGMOD  |        2 |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

As you can see the result is correct but doubled, as I just want 1 time the name.

Other question, how to modify the number parameter for only one conference, for example get all the author that published at least 3 SIGMOD and at least 1 PVLDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the `journal` , don't select it, it is splitting your results. Also, normal filters need to be placed in the `WHERE` clause, not the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT author.name, COUNT(*)
  FROM author
 INNER JOIN author_has_publication
    ON author.idAuthor = author_has_publication.Author_idAuthor
 INNER JOIN publication
    ON author_has_publication.Publication_idPublication =
       publication.idPublication
WHERE  publication.journal IN('PVLDB','SIGMOD')       
 GROUP BY author.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN publication.journal = 'SIGMOD' THEN 1 END) >= 2
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN publication.journal = 'PVLDB' THEN 1 END) >= 2;
```

For the second question, use this `HAVING()` clause :

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN publication.journal = 'SIGMOD' THEN 1 END) >= 3
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN publication.journal = 'PVLDB' THEN 1 END) >= 1;
```

Comment: this does not work because it returns also the authors that have less than 2 publication for PVLDB and SIGMOD conference, the difficulty is to count separatly each conference publicationns

Comment: I misunderstood the question, should work now. @Mayeulsgc

Comment: thanks it's working, I was having a lot of trouble with the use of GROUP BY, WHERE and HAVING in a same request